# Control Mouse with Classic controller joystick in wminput/cwiid

Tags: 13.10

I have installed wmgui and cwiid. I am attempting to get it set up for gaming, so I want the right joystick to control the mouse, and the left to control KEY_W, KEY_A, KEY_S, and KEY_D.
I have tried the following in /etc/cwiid/wminput/buttons:

```
Classic.RStick.X = REL_X
Classic.RStick.Y = REL_Y
```

but it just sticks the mouse in the bottom-right corner of the screen, unmovable.
How would I make it actually move the mouse, and have the LStick move W,A,S,and D?

EDIT: Using ubuntu 13.10, not 13.04

Comment: Sorry, but your Ubuntu version 13.04 has reached the end-of-life period. Please, upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: Changed version (I checked, I have 13.10)

Comment: It seems that it won't be possible without creating a plugin for cwiid. Note that when assigning nunchuck's analog stick to mouse movement in default config, it says `Plugin.nunchuk_mouse.X = REL_X`. I suspect that `Classic.RStick.X` gives output that is uderstandable for emulated joysticks, but not for mouse.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to play a modern game, chances are that it supports Xbox360 controllers. There's a way to emulate such a controller using a Classic Controller and a piece of software called `xboxdrv` (`wiicd` is pretty much abandoned right now).

[Here's the details](https://github.com/abstrakraft/cwiid/issues/18#issuecomment-145367407).

The gist of it is this: After connecting the wiimote to your pc, 
run

```
sudo xboxdrv --dpad-as-button --evdev /dev/input/event$1 --evdev-absmap ABS_HAT1X=x1,ABS_HAT1Y=y1,ABS_HAT2X=x2,ABS_HAT2Y=y2,ABS_HAT3Y=LT,ABS_HAT3X=RT --evdev-keymap=BTN_A=A,BTN_B=B,BTN_X=X,BTN_Y=Y,KEY_PREVIOUS=Back,KEY_NEXT=Start,BTN_MODE=Guide,KEY_DOWN=DOWN,KEY_UP=UP,KEY_LEFT=LEFT,KEY_RIGHT=RIGHT,BTN_TL2=LB,BTN_TR2=RB --mimic-xpad
```

and play your game :)

PS Big thanks to GitHub user [benbaptist](https://github.com/benbaptist), who saved me a lot of time and frustration with finding a solution to that one!